# How to compare nested properties between lists

Tags: c#

So, I'm basically creating a version control-like system. I have the following class `Form`:

```
public class Form
{
    public long Id {get; private set;}
    /* among other things */
}
```

Then, another class like so:

```
public class Conflict
{
    List<Form> localForms;
    List<Form> remoteForms;
    /* among other things */
}
```

and then a main class that maintains a `List` of `Conflict`s.

```
public class Main
{
    List<Conflict> conflicts;

    /*
     * more stuff...
    */

    public void AddFormConflict(List<Form> locals, List<Form> remotes)
    {
        ...what goes here?
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that when a new `Conflict` object is about to be added, it doesn't contain duplicate data; in other words, I want to compare `Id`s of the `List<Form> locals` argument with `Id`s contained by the `localForms` member of the `conflicts` list. And same for the remotes as well. Furthermore, I not only want to find out whether or not such a match exists, but I also want to get a reference to it.

Basically long story short, I want to compare the properties in a list of objects with corresponding properties in another similarly-structured list of objects... which are contained by another class which is in a list.

I'm pretty sure there's gotta be some relatively simple way to do something like this with linq in about 2-3 lines, right? I just can't for the life of me wrap my head around all the layers! Ugh. Help please?

Comment: I think this question is off topic for stack overflow.  Try reading the help section on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ to see if it would be a good fit there.

Comment: @roryap: Off topic why? It seems to be a specific programming problem which is the first item in the list of on topic things at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Chris -- What is the *specific* programming *problem* (i.e. error/issue/general thing that's not working)?  It seems to me to be a better fit for programmers because it sounds like it's more about design.

Comment: Comparing nested properties between lists. I'm not going to say its a particularly clear question but I am pretty confident there is a specific problem here and not just "I want to create a VCS. Help!". It may be that it will be a better fit for programmers (I don't know, I don't hang out there) but that isn't the same as off topic here. I'm sure I've seen plenty of similar questions around (to the extent that I wonder if this is a duplicate).

Comment: This site is about *problems*, where "problem" does not mean "I'm trying to build this thing and don't quite know how", rather it means "I'm getting this error" or "this doesn't work and I can't figure out why"

Comment: @roryap: I think we are going to have to agree to disagree since I see a problem and you don't and comments isn't really a place to debate this. Let voting and consensus do its job. :)

Comment: @Pojo: This would be clearer if you coudl describe more precisely the nature of your comparison? Is it just the id that you need to check to determine if something is a duplicate or do you need to check all properties? Also is a `Conflict` only a duplicate of an existing one if the locals and remotes have the same data in both lists or is any overlap of data a problem?

Comment: @Chris I'm only interested in overlapping `Id`s. What I'm trying to solve is the case where multiple `Conflict` objects are created, but they contain data that describes the same "conflict" conceptually—that is, the `Form`s having the same `Id`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the properties public

```
public class Conflict
{
    public List<Form> localForms { get; set; }
    public List<Form> remoteForms { get; set; }
    /* among other things */
}
```

You can check for duplicates like this

```
public class Main
{
    List<Conflict> conflicts;

    public void AddFormConflict(List<Form> locals, List<Form> remotes)
    {
        if (conflicts.Any(c => c.localForms.Any(lf => locals.Any(lc => lf.Id == lc.Id))))
        {
            //duplicate found for localForms
        }
        //similarly check for remoteForms
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh thank you, that's exactly what I was talking about. :) Just confused myself with all the nested Linq-ness.